# Function works in HTML, but when inserting the asp.net part It no longer works

Tags: .net

I've followed the introduction given by Microsoft on ASP.Net( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/entering-data)  and linking forms to a database. The HTML part works and also my modifications (like geotagging and other things) work as well. However, when I insert the functions to insert the form data into a database it no longer compiles due to syntax errors. I've tried a .net framework as well. Can someone help?

Comment: put your code here and update your question

Answer (score -1):

With the information given we can't do so much (post all your code and tell us where exactly is the syntax error).

Maybe you have not created database, here is in the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data , but i'm not 100% sure.